# Android studio lower pane full width under MacOS

Tags: macos, user-interface, android-studio

i would like to have the lower pane (Android Monitor in the screenshot) to be full width in Android Studio. I mean it should be full screen width (like overlapping the left project pane)

[image: android studio]

Any tips how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

click this as image showing to collapse project view.

Comment: well, but i want the left pane to be there... but the same height like the main editor view

Comment: After this,click left you will make it.

Comment: mmh. sorry i dont get it.. if i press on "project" again its the same situation as before